# Staying outside of EU on blue card

Tags: germany, resident-permit, eu, blue-card

I have EU blue card from last 2 years and I’m working for a company in Germany. During covid my company allowed to work fully remote and I came to my home country in Asia and working remotely from here (paying taxes in Germany). Its been 5 months now, should I have to go back to Germany now? Would it affect my re-entry in Germany?

Answer (score 0):

Periods upto 6 months outside of Germany are *generally* allowed without any side effects on the Residence permit.

A BlueCard is an **exception** to this rule, where 12 months is allowed.

For any longer periods, an application must be made **before** you leave.

A foreign assignment (Auslandseinsatz) for a German firm outside of Germany is generally considered a valid reason for a longer absence.

So if you are planning to return (i.e. take up residence again), you should do so before the 12 months are up.

Comment: Periods upto 6 months outside of Germany are not generally allowed, rather they are only allowed for leaving Germany temporarily. If the OP intention was to leave in other country permanently, his residence permit might expire immediately.